# What is the best way to report unusual answering and upvoting?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

After answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036705/how-submit-a-form-from-jquery-function-without-id/) I noticed that [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036705/how-submit-a-form-from-jquery-function-without-id/24036962#24036962) had appeared which was a direct clone of my own, word for word, simply adding 'try this'. Within seconds the duplicate answer had 2 upvotes.

I then went through the users' history and found several [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272190/how-to-make-countdown-timer-to-not-reset-on-page-refresh/23467373#23467373) [occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841389/form-submit-without-going-to-the-target-page/23841765#23841765) where his answers are duplicates (adding minor formatting changes) of pre-existing ones. Again these answers have a couple of upvotes which itself seems a little odd given the late nature of the answer and low popularity of the question in one case.

I have flagged each of these answers, but it is difficult to show in the flag that it appears to be part of a larger problem. For my own future reference, what is the accepted best practice to highlight this issue (as a whole) to moderators?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649237/cant-display-data-in-my-php-sessions/23649397#23649397

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Flag any of the answers and use the "other" option to explain what you've found in as much detail as you have available.

You appear to have found a sockpuppet/voting ring - which will be dealt with.

Comment: Bwahahahahahaaaa!!!1!!1!!one!!!11!!eleven!!

Comment: Put them in the [Iron Maiden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_maiden_(torture_device))

Comment: @Paul, or we could put them in the [Iron Maiden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Maiden), too!

Comment: @AndrewBarber That might be going too far.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_in_psychological_operations

Comment: Consider two users who would usually (frequently) comment on each other's post: _+1 for an elegant solution_ or something similar.  Does that count as a _ring_?

Comment: @devnull - If there's no voting then it doesn't count. If there is voting then it most certainly does.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks.  Looks like there will be more meat to put some more voting rings at rest!